# Having trouble adding an element to a string vector

Tags: c++, string, vector, switch-statement, push-back

I'm writing a simple journal like function, however I can't seem to fathom out how to generate a new element of the vector by passing the value the user enters. I am new to programming so the answer might well be obvious :/ I get no errors when I compile the program but the code for adding in a journal entry seems to have no effect. Any ideas?

This is the program below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    bool running = true;

    while (running = true) 
    {

    vector<string> journal;
    vector<string>::const_iterator iter;
    int count = 1;

    journal.push_back("Day 1. Found some beans.");
    journal.push_back("Must remember not to eat beans");
    journal.push_back("Found some idiot who traded beans for a cow!");

    cout << "Journal Tester.\n\n";


    cout << "1 - View Journal\n2 - Add journal entry\n";
    cout << "3 - Quit\n";
    cout << "\nPlease choose: ";

    string newentry;
    int choice; 
    cin >> choice;
    cout << endl;

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        for (iter = journal.begin(); iter != journal.end(); ++iter)
    {

        cout << "Entry " << count << ": \n";
        cout << *iter << endl; 
        ++ count;
    }
        count = 1;
        break;

    case 2: 

        cout << "\nYou write: ";
        cin >> newentry; 

        cout << endl << newentry;
        journal.push_back(newentry); 

        break;

    }

    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note `=` sets a value, `==` compares two values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
vector<string> journal;
```

is recreated on each iteration of the `while` loop so when the code that prints the elements operates on a new empty `vector`. Move the definition of `journal` to outside of the `while` loop:

```
vector<string> journal;
while (running) // Note removed assignment here.
{
}
```

And the hardcoded values that are `push_back()`ed into the `vector` may also need to moved outside of the loop if you do not want these repeatedly added.

Comment: Doh! I spent so much time looking at passing the value, I didn't think about where my declaration was! (I'm a novice, so I keep moving things  around "thinking" it will make things more efficient!) Thank you very much for that!

Answer (score 1):

The vectors are declared *inside* the "while" loop, so they are local to it, and get created anew for each iteration of the loop. That means the program forgets its own past every time around. Move the vector declarations *before* the loop and things will improve greatly!

Answer (score 0):

create vector once only, before loop:

```
vector<string> journal;
while (running) // <- also change this to avoid inf loop
{
 string s("me");
 journal.push_back(s);
 //.. do things with your vector "journal"
}
```

alse be careful what you do in loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your vector variable is instantiated inside the scope of the `while` loop. That means it is newly created in every turn of the loop, the data that was added with `case 2:` of the switch statement is lost.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
     #include <vector>

     using namespace std;
 vector<string> journal;//**SHOULD NOT WRITE INSIDE THE LOOP**
 int main()

  {
bool running = true;

while (running = true) 
{


vector<string>::const_iterator iter;
int count = 1;

journal.push_back("Day 1. Found some beans.");
journal.push_back("Must remember not to eat beans");
journal.push_back("Found some idiot who traded beans for a cow!");

cout << "Journal Tester.\n\n";


cout << "1 - View Journal\n2 - Add journal entry\n";
cout << "3 - Quit\n";
cout << "\nPlease choose: ";

string newentry;
int choice; 
cin >> choice;
cout << endl;

switch (choice)
{
case 1:
    for (iter = journal.begin(); iter != journal.end(); ++iter)
{

    cout << "Entry " << count << ": \n";
    cout << *iter << endl; 
    ++ count;
}
    count = 1;
    break;

case 2: 

    cout << "\nYou write: ";
    cin >> newentry; 

    cout << endl << newentry;
    journal.push_back(newentry); 

    break;

}

} 

return 0;
```

}